# What is subject of the second sentence joined by "and"?

Tags: conjunctions, subjects, compound-subjects

In some logical reasoning questions, I get stuck in the following type of sentences.

1. Car A is parked somewhere in the left of Car B and is parked somewhere in the right of Car C.
2. Jack is at the right of Rose and is facing north.

Now my query is what is the *subject of the second part* after "and" i.e. in 1. Car C is right of which Car? In 2. who is facing north?

It will be helpful if someone can provide the sentences so that the subject switches and give some more interesting examples of these kind.

Comment: By my understanding, _and is_ indicates that the second clause also describes the subject of the sentence. Otherwise, (1) would read _...Car B, which is..._ and (2) _...Rose, who is..._

Comment: They are both coordination constructions each containing a coordination of two VPs.  In 1. "car A" is subject of both bracketed VPs:  "Car A [is parked somewhere to the left of Car B] and [is parked somewhere to the right of Car C]". Similarly 2. has "Jack" as subject of both VPs: "Jack [is at the right of Rose] and [is facing north]".

Comment: "Car A is parked somewhere in the left of Car B" suggests A is parked inside B; it should be "parked somewhere to the left".

Comment: [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20conjunction%20reduction) removes repeated (and therefore predictable) material in conjuncts. _Bill washed the dishes and Bill dried the dishes_ ===> _Bill washed and dried the dishes_.

Comment: The term 'conjunction reduction' relates to transformational grammar. In straightforward traditional descriptive grammar, it is sufficient to say that the OP's sentences are coordination constructions containing a coordination of VPs.